# subsets of a generating set of a free group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Is it true that, given any free group $F$ and any set $S\subseteq F$ which generates $F$, there is a subset $T\subseteq S$ which is a free generating set for $F$?

It would be great if you could give me some literature recommendations.

Comment: I see you had used the axiom-of-choice tag. Was this perhaps meant to be a question on *infinite* generating sets? (It still false. However, you could ask if every infinite generating set has a finite generating set, and then I would have to think about the answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $\{2,3\}$ is a generator set of the free group $\mathbb{Z}$, but no proper subset generates the group.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the silly question! Do you know in what situations I can expect a free generating subset?

Comment: @Phil Your question wasn't silly - it is related to the classic result which states that if a subset $S$ of the free group $F_n$ generates $F$ and $|S|=n$ then $S$ generates $F_n$ freely.